# mail command of unix

Tags: perl, email, unix

I am using the mail command of unix in a perl script. I specify the 'to', 'cc', 'subject' and 'body' of the mail. I do not specify the from address. Where is the from address picked from? Pls help

Comment: What is your mail utilities? You can edit header to modify the from address.

Answer (score 3):

There are portable libraries for handling email as daxim and David W mention, but if you want a quick fix, this works under linux if your `mail` command  uses `bsd-mailx` (as it does on my machine)...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$BODY = "Hello self";
$RECIPIENT = "destination\@email.local";
$FROM = "mike\@localhost";
$SUBJECT = "some subject here";
$CMD = qq(echo "$BODY" | mail -a "From: $FROM" -s $SUBJECT $RECIPIENT);
exec($CMD);
```

If you have more questions about the unix `mail` command, try `man mail` from your shell prompt.

Comment: i cant see the upvote button because my eyes started bleeding from all uc variable names.. i just clicked somewhere anyway ;)

Comment: @mugen, apologies; many of my peers use all caps variable names for [constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Perl).  I used a lot of constants so the code would be self-documenting.

Comment: ah, i did not know that before. Makes sense. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Answer does not fit the question, you can do better than just a general pointer to the documentation.

Comment: @daxim, your comment makes no sense.  I did far more than just pointing to the documentation.  If you have improvements for my answer, then please be specific.

Comment: OK, I'll be verbose. The question was: "Where is the From address picked from?" You did not answer this. You answered the question "How do I override a From header/set a default From header?" that no one asked. Can you see that now? - Furthermore, you referenced the documentation in a very general and unspecific way. Disappointingly, it's not even a hyper-link to a Web resource. You should cite materials properly and quote the specific part that is pertinent to the supplicant's question, or else this sort of pointer reeks too much of "RTFM, it's somewhere in there" which is frowned upon on SO.

Comment: @daxim, I did not answer the question **you** wanted.  The reality is that there are *multiple* ways to set the "From" header, and `mail -a` is one of them.  RTFM is frowned on, which is why I gave an answer that solved the problem so he wouldn't have to RTFM.  Nevertheless, I don't spoon-feed people without teaching them how to use a spoon

Comment: "Where is the from address picked from?" is a direct quote from the question, not something I wanted. If you really believe that, nuts to you, nuts to you. -1 for buggy code due to not including `strict` and `warnings`: the arrays `@email` and `@localhost` are not defined.

Comment: @daxim, since when do you decide to pretend I used strict in my code.  There is no requirement to use it, and even Larry Wall posts code without it.  Thank you for finally pointing out the escaping issue...

Answer (score 1):

The `mail` command on most system nowadays is [Heirloom mailx](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx.html). It claims compatibility with POSIX, so the information I give here *should* be good for any well-behaving `mail` command.

The `From` address is set by:

- either the `user@domain` as returned by the appropriate POSIX system calls (see shell commands `whoami` and `domainname -f` for a different way to access them)
- or set by the `from` environment variable
- or set by the `-r` command line option (going to be deprecated?)

---

Obligatory Clippy: Hi! I see you are trying to **send mail from Perl**. Did you mean to use **[Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSender)/[Email::Simple](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSimple)** instead?

Comment: Mike, I undid your change because `-a` is for attachments.

Comment: Well, that claim is just wrong, see the [documentation](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html), and I did verify just now (on Linux) that `-a From: …` gives the error message `No such file or directory`. I think your downvote was unjustified.

Comment: The only option for [`mailx`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html) in send mode that is stipulated by POSIX is '`-s "subject"`'.  You're probably still correct about where the From address comes from - though POSIX does not mandate the `$from` environment variable or the `-r` option.  I also agree with using Perl Email modules rather than `mailx`.

Comment: @daxim, for someone so pedantic about my answer, perhaps you should know better than to gripe about this... try quoting the args for `-a` as I did in my answer.  BTW, I used `mail`, not `mailx`

Comment: That mistake in my comment would be worth pointing out if it actually made a difference. Exact paste for your pedanticness: `LANG=C mail -a 'From: daxim@localhost' daxim␤From: daxim@localhost: No such file or directory␤`

Comment: Direct paste from my machine... `echo "hello from daxim" | mail -a "From: daxim@localhost" -s "daxim secretly wants to be your friend" myuser@gmail.com` seems to send mail to my gmail account.  FYI... my debian box symlinks `mail` to `bsd-mailx`.

Comment: echo "hello from daxim" | mail -a "From: daxim@localhost" -s "daxim secretly wants to be your friend" myuser@gmail.com    does not work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the mail command linecommand! Use [Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html).

The `mail` command may not even be configured on a particular system, and it won't work on Windows. Meanwhile, `Net::SMTP` is a standard Perl module that should be available on all systems.

Never used it before? Read the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) and try it out. That's how you learn.

Comment: I don't think that Net::SMTP is a good recommendation. It requires the user to be intimately familiar with the numerous Internet mail RFCs. [In my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6099796#6101474), I point out a solution that abstracts away the boring and fault-prone low-level details.

Comment: @daxim, perhaps I can help the OP figure out the relevant mail RFCs... as it happens, [Net::SMTP comes with an example](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html#EXAMPLES).   +1 David W